# check out from a machine and check in to other tfs

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I have check out my project from a machine with this IP : 192.168.0.5 and I want check in it to other machine with this IP: 192.168.0.199. but when I want to go online vs2010 get me 192.168.0.5 machine to check in.

Comment: When you go to this second PC 192.168.0.199 - are your checked out changes visible? If yes, how?

Comment: I think you are saying that you have two different TFS servers. Can you clarify your question to indicate whether the IP addresses are dev machines or TFS servers?

Comment: @HolisticDeveloper you might be right - I 'm rolling back my edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way to approach what you are after, is to shelve your pending changes in machine #1, unshelve in machine #2 & check in as you need. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181404%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for a description.